# Ubuntu slows game down

Tags: nvidia, graphics, games, steam

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with Nvidia 1060 (3GB) card. I noticed that when I play games (Counter Strike GO), the system would slow down the game somehow. In the first couple of minutes, the game is running 120 FPS. But after that, it gets below 60 FPS.

I am wandering if this is some feature in Ubuntu that I can turn on and off.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's your GPU throttling, what is your GPU temp when it reaches below 60fps?

Comment: @meisme it's about 90C.